# Sum DataFrame row values grouped by column in another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames as follows:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'Code':['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL','MNO'],       
    '2000': [19647.0, 1814135.0, 1864791.0,261630.0, 20758.0], 
    '2001': [1762621.0,1814135.0,1864791.0,1914573.0,1965598.0], 
    '2002': [25998340.0,26920466.0,207633.0,28813463.0,29784193.0] }) 
df2.set_index('Code')


df3 = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'Code':['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL','MNO'],       
    'Groups': ['Group A', 'Group B', 'Group C','Group B', 'Group A']})
df3.set_index('Code')
```

I need to get total values for each year by the respective group. eg. the sum for the year 2000 for **Group A** is 40405.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 
'Code':['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL','MNO'],       
'2000': [19647.0, 1814135.0, 1864791.0,261630.0, 20758.0], 
'2001': [1762621.0,1814135.0,1864791.0,1914573.0,1965598.0], 
'2002': [25998340.0,26920466.0,207633.0,28813463.0,29784193.0] }) 


df3 = pd.DataFrame({ 
'Code':['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL','MNO'],       
'Groups': ['Group A', 'Group B', 'Group C','Group B', 'Group A']})

df3 = df3.merge(df2, on=['Code'])
df3.groupby(['Groups']).sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

For the grouper `map` the index of `df2` to the 'Groups' and then take the sum. Also you set the index you never assign it back so you should do `df2=df2.set_index('Code')`, though it's not necessary to have them as the index to solve this.

```
#df2=df2.set_index('Code')
#df3=df3.set_index('Code')
df2.groupby(df2.index.map(df3['Groups'])).sum()

#              2000       2001        2002
#Code                                     
#Group A    40405.0  3728219.0  55782533.0
#Group B  2075765.0  3728708.0  55733929.0
#Group C  1864791.0  1864791.0    207633.0
```